# Facebook Pages, ask which page user choose, and take id, name, and ratings IOS SWIFT 3-4

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First sorry for my English, I'm a French developer.

for 1 week, I read and reread the Facebook documentation but it does not work.
This is my problem:
On Xcode, I can create the connection with Facebook, the user can connect with his account and I managed to recover his image and surname / first name.
On another page, I ask for access token for [manage_pages], the application asks permission but when the user has several pages they do not propose to manage one, Authorization I can not retrieve the ID or name of the Facebook page. I leave you the code on the Options page which allows you to request authorization to connect your Facebook page after the user presses a button.

I tried with access graph: / me / accounts ... etc without success. It's really because I really have no idea that I'm coming to you. Thank you in advance for your answers !

```
@IBAction func connect_Pages(_ sender: Any) {
        loginButtonClicked()
    }

func loginButtonClicked() {
    let login:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager.init()
    login.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["manage_pages"], from: self) { (resultPAge, error) in
        if((error) != nil) {
                            print("error")

                }
        else if (resultPAge?.isCancelled)! {
            print("cancel")

        }
        else {

                            if (resultPAge?.grantedPermissions.contains("manage_pages"))! {

if resultPAge?.token == nil {
print("error")
}
 else {
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/accounts", parameters: ["fields" : "access_token, name, id"])
let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
print("connect")
connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
if let dataRecup = result as? [String:AnyObject] {
if let idPage = dataRecup["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
if let nomPage = idPage["name"] as? String {
print("Resultat : \(nomPage)")
}
}
}
})
}
}
}
}

}
```

**EDIT :**

I just removed the first / for the graphpath, but a new problem appeared, I retrieve the information from the page (accessToken, id and name) but there are no quotation marks! The application can not recover it to separate in JSON.

Comment: You need to go via `/me/accounts` to get the access tokens for the pages the user manages.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but I have already tried, I have no answer. It does not change anything. I have no return.

Comment: Then I’d suggest you make a debug output of your user token, and then using that, try the request in Graph API Explorer first to see if it is a problem with permissions, or with your code.

Comment: I have this error : "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)""

Comment: If you are asking for the `access_token` field only, then you will only get that field (plus the page id) - but you are trying to access the page name here as well by the looks of it, so you would need to request that field as well.

Comment: The user token seems to work because I can quit and return the application it opens the facebook account again. But it is the transition to the Facebook page. The application for authorization to manage works, I accept, and nothing happens, I can not recover anything. How would you like me to test on the Open Graph API?

Comment: I have already tried from my account, the open graph asks me permission to manage the pages (I can choose the one I want or not) and I manage to retrieve the name and id of the pages that I ' administered. However, on Xcode, facebook does not propose to choose the page, nor to focus on a single one to recover the necessary information.
I do not know if I make myself understood.

Comment: I have already tried with : (graphPath: "/me/accounts", parameters: ["fields" : "access_token, id"]) and ask if let idPage = dataRecup["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                                                if let idPage = idPage["id"] as? String {
                                                    print("Resultat : \(idPage)")
                                                    
                                                } but no result too.

Comment: Users get asked to confirm permissions only once; once you granted your app the permission, you will not be asked to confirm that same permission again when the login dialog is shown the next time. If you need to repeat the process for testing purposes, then you need to remove that permission via an API call, or remove the app completely from the user’s Facebook settings first.

Comment: I copy the last code I had done, but I have already tried many things before. I modified the path, the parameters, my request ... But I never have a result! While the connection to the profile works perfectly.
I put myself in tester (because it would seem that it is necessary to make accept its application by facebook) before being able to acceder the pages (except for the testers)

Comment: Yes I know, but I just ask for an additional authorization, that of [manage_pages], I do not ask for the same authorization. It seems that we can not ask permission from [public_pofile] and [manage_pages] in the same query.

Comment: Well no, you have to request reading and publishing permissions separately on mobile (at least when using Facebook’s SDKs.)

Comment: Yep i see that, is for that I create a new swift file for Options and make permissions for [manage_pages] but doesn't work ... If you see solutions ...?

Comment: I have this too : "Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug"

Comment: And when I launch from my phone : "network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates"